How to drop only the null cells in pandas dataframe and shift the values up?
I can drop entire row/column using drop(), how to drop a single cell and shifting the next value up without dropping the entire row. Is there any in-built function for this?
My table looks like this,



SMA_5
Pandas_5




54
nan


34
nan


54
nan


32
nan


51
89


94
90


51
70


32
31


...
...


...etc
...etc



and i want the result like this:



SMA_5
Pandas_5




54
89


34
90


54
70


32
31


51
98


94
13


51
23


32
13


...
...


...etc
...etc




You're not shifting, but duplicating here. What should happens if you have more/less NaNs than values afterwards? Or inner NaNs?

Or do you just want df['Pandas_5'] = df['Pandas_5'].fillna(df['SMA_5'])?

Notice how the duplicated values make your example ambiguous. Please improve the example and clearly explain the logic.

i dont want any duplicated values, its just shifting the subsequent values up within the column while keeping the rest of the dataframe intact

You'll end up with NaN at the end of the column and you're okay with this, right?

yes it will be okay

As explained in comments, the expected logic is not fully clear.
Assuming you just want to shift up (i.e. move the NaNs down):
def shift_up(s):
    x = s.dropna()
    return x.set_axis(s.index[:len(x)]).reindex(s.index) # reindex is optional

df['Pandas_5'] = shift_up(df['Pandas_5'])

Variant using a list:
def shift_up(s):
    return (x:=s.dropna().tolist())+[None]*(len(s)-len(x))

Output:
   SMA_5  Pandas_5
0     54      89.0
1     34      90.0
2     54      70.0
3     32      31.0
4     51       NaN
5     94       NaN
6     51       NaN
7     32       NaN

Assuming you want to shift the non-NaNs up and keep the original values intact:
def shift_up(s):
    x = s.dropna()
    return s.fillna(x.set_axis(s.index[:len(x)]))

df['Pandas_5'] = shift_up(df['Pandas_5'])

If you insist on a one-liner:
df['Pandas_5'] = ((s:=df['Pandas_5']).fillna((x := s.dropna())
                  .set_axis(s.index[:len(x)]))
                 )

Output:
   SMA_5  Pandas_5
0     54      89.0
1     34      90.0
2     54      70.0
3     32      31.0
4     51      89.0
5     94      90.0
6     51      70.0
7     32      31.0


@Vitalizzare indeed thanks :)

I've figured out using df["Pandas_5"] = df["Pandas_5"].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) does the job of dropping NaN cells and shifting the next values up within the same column. @mozway @Vitalizzare

Honestly, I didn't understand the last part with fillna; I'm not sure why it should work in the general case. Maybe it's because I assume NaN is randomly positioned along the entire column, not necessarily only at its beginning. But I support the first option.

@ImBatman that would only work if you have a range index, if not this will break up the alignment.

@Vitalizzare the second option will fillna requires all NaN to be in the beginning (thus my question, which remained unanswered)

You've changed the first option, why? Seems like it's not shifting up anymore, is it?

@mozway its not compulsory that the Nan's can only be in the beginning, it could be any row of the same column, if there are values below the nan, it is supposed to go up. My main aim was just to remove Nan's and subsequently fill the values that were below it.

@Vitalizzare wrong copy/paste ::facepalm::

@ImBatman the first option is doing that as you expect. I guess the second option can be ignored since you seem to want the first one ;)

@mozway yes the first one will work as expected.

Also @mozway you were right about breaking the alignment , i had the continuous range so it worked for me, had to be careful with what you said.

Case 1. NaN is randomly positioned along the entire column
I believe sorting can be used here with key= specified so that it returns True for NaN values moving them down and False for others moving them up. For example:
df.transform(lambda x: x.sort_values(key=lambda x: x.isna()).values, axis=0)

Let's see how it can work with an example:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [None, 'a', 'd', None, 'c', 'C', 'c'],
    'B': [1, 4, None, 2, 10, None, 3]
})
print(df)

#       A     B
# 0  None   1.0
# 1     a   4.0
# 2     d   NaN
# 3  None   2.0
# 4     c  10.0
# 5     C   NaN
# 6     c   3.0

result = df.transform(lambda x: x.sort_values(key=lambda x: x.isna()).values)
print(result)

#       A     B
# 0     a   1.0
# 1     d   4.0
# 2     c   2.0
# 3     C  10.0
# 4     c   3.0
# 5  None   NaN
# 6  None   NaN

Note, we need the function to return values without an index, so they won’t be aligned with the initial index by merging and placing values back where they were. Also, we can drop axis=0 since it's the default value for the parameter.
Case 2. Empty cells positioned at the beginning or end of a column
Suppose all NaN values are placed either at the very beginning or at the end of a column. In this case, we could use shift to move each column up. To determine the number of periods to shift, we can use first_valid_index. For example:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [None, None, 'a', 'd', 'c',  'b'],
    'B': [None,    1,   4,   3,   2, None]
}, index=[*'bcaxyz'])

result = (
    df.reset_index(drop=True)      # set a numeric index to determin first valid index positions
    .transform(lambda x: x.shift(-x.first_valid_index()))
    .set_index(df.index)           # reset the original index
)
print(result)

#       A    B
# b     a  1.0
# c     d  4.0
# a     c  3.0
# x     b  2.0
# y  None  NaN
# z  None  NaN

If no fancy index used, then the following line will be enough:
df.transform(lambda x: x.shift(-x.first_valid_index()))


See also:

sort_values
transform
shift


Yes this seems good, i was expecting this kind of result.

Another possible solution, whose steps are:

The dropna method is used to remove rows where the Pandas_5 column has missing values.

The reset_index method is then called to reset the index of the resulting dataframe.

The join method merges this cleaned dataframe back with the original dataframe df on their indices, with a left join. The lsuffix='_' parameter adds a suffix to the columns of the left dataframe to avoid naming conflicts.

The [df.columns] part ensures that only the columns originally present in df are selected from the joined dataframe.

Finally, the combine_first method is used to fill in any missing values in the joined dataframe with the corresponding values from the original dataframe df.


(df.join(
    df.dropna(subset='Pandas_5').reset_index(), lsuffix='_')[df.columns]
.combine_first(df))

Output:
SMA_5  Pandas_5
0   51.0      89.0
1   94.0      90.0
2   51.0      70.0
3   32.0      31.0
4   51.0      89.0
5   94.0      90.0
6   51.0      70.0
7   32.0      31.0

